# Map the 32bit integers into 32 bins, with 1,2,4..2^31 consecutive integers per bin

Tags: c, algorithm, bit-manipulation

For a 32 bit integer, divide it into 32 bins of consecutive integers such that there are twice as many integers in each successive bin. The first bin contains 0, the second 0..1, etc up to 0..2^31-1.

The fastest algorithm I could come up with, given a 32 bit integer i, is 5 cycles on an i7 (bit scan is 3 cycles):

```
// bin is the number of leading zeroes, and then we clear the msb to get item
bin_index = bsr(i)
item = i ^ (1 << bin_index)
```

Or equivalently (well it stores the items 0..2^(32-1) in bin 0 and 0 in bin 31, but that doesn't matter):

```
// bin is the number of trailing zeroes, and then we shift down by that many bits + 1
bin_index = bsf(i)
item = i >> (bin_index + 1)
```

In each case the bin index is encoded as the number of leading/trailing zero bits, with a 1 to separate them from the item number. You could do the same with leading or trailing ones and a zero to separate them. Neither works with i=0, but that's not important.

The mapping between integers and the bins/items can be completely arbitrary, so long as twice as many consecutive integers end up in each successive bin and the total number of integers in the bins sums to 2^32-1. Can you think of a more efficient algorithm to bin the 32 integers on an i7? Keep in mind an i7 is superscalar so any operations that don't depend on each other can execute in parallel, up to the throughput for each instruction type.

Comment: Since you mention i7, you could try to convert the integers to floating point and extract the exponent to get a biased bin_index. Zero requires special attention.

Comment: Looks like it's not a win, http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf puts the operation as 3+2 cycles on an i7 (not sure what the +2 means here, but it's irrelevant as 3 is more than enough to kill any possible gains.

Comment: I was more like thinking SSE unit and executing at least 4 operations in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve your algorithm by trying to sort the data first before counting zeros.

For example , compare it to 2^31 first and if its greater put it in that bin, otherwise go on and count trailing zeros. With this you now have half your data set put into its bin in 2 instructions...probably two cycles. The other half would take a bit longer but the net result would be an improvement. You can likely optimize even further following this line if thought.

I guess this would also be dependent on the efficiency ofbranch prediction.

Comment: The expected speed would be 4 cycles per number for a sorted array (probably 2), but I doubt that sorting can be done in ~1-3 cycles per element to break even.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but I'm not able to sort the dataset. I do know that most of the time the values would be smaller than 2^31. But half the dataset in 2 instructions and half with a branch miss is definitely not a win ((7+2+brnach miss)/2 > 4.5 But there's a variant solution that combines bins 0 and 1 (the others stay the same.) Then I'd have 3/4 of the dataset in 2 instructions - a predictable branch. And it becomes (7+2+branch miss)/4 > 2.25. If we take the value of 15 cycles for a branch miss on an i7 that I found online in a random pdf, it would be (7+2+15)/4 = 6. Still a loss :(